# Group a StaticText with a TextCtrl in wxPython

Tags: python, user-interface, wxpython, python-3.9

I want to build a UI for editing ID3v2 tags of mp3 files. I need a list of StaticText - TextCtrl for editing different tags. Instead of creating StaticText and TextCtrl separately I would like to write a widget that combines them both.
I want it to look sth like this:

[image]

My first idea was to extend a BoxSizer and prepopulate it with a StaticText and a TextCtrl

```py
import wx

class LabelTextSizer(wx.BoxSizer):
    def __init__(self, label):
        super().__init__(wx.HORIZONTAL)

        self.label = wx.StaticText(self, label=label)
        self.text = wx.TextCtrl(self)

        self.Add(self.label)
        self.Add(self.text)
```

but it does not seam to work like i expect it to:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Tron\repo\rex-song-tagger\main.py", line 58, in <module>
    frm = HelloFrame(None, title='Hello World 2')
  File "D:\Tron\repo\rex-song-tagger\main.py", line 25, in __init__
    sizer = LabelTextSizer('Title')
  File "D:\Tron\repo\rex-song-tagger\LabelTextSizer.py", line 25, in __init__
    self.label = wx.StaticText(self, label=label)
TypeError: StaticText(): arguments did not match any overloaded call:
  overload 1: too many arguments
  overload 2: argument 1 has unexpected type 'LabelTextSizer'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

How would you do it the wx-way?

Comment: You want a widget not a sizer. `wx.ListBox` could be a contender.

Answer (score 1):

You have used the LabelTextSizer (a sizer) as the parent of the StaticText and TextCtrl widgets, but this must be a wx.window (e.g your frame or panel), [see wxPython docs](https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.StaticText.html#methods)

This works:

```
import wx


class MainFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(None, *args, **kwargs)

        self.panel = MainPanel(self)
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(self.panel)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)
        self.Show()


class MainPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent, *args, **kwargs)
        labeltext_1 = LabelTextSizer(self, 'Title', size=(300, -1), style=wx.TE_PROCESS_TAB)
        labeltext_2 = LabelTextSizer(self, 'Artist', size=(300, -1), style=wx.TE_PROCESS_TAB)
        labeltext_3 = LabelTextSizer(self, 'Track', size=(300, -1), style=wx.TE_PROCESS_TAB)
        labeltext_1.text.SetHint("TIT2 ...")
        labeltext_2.text.SetHint("TPE2 ...")
        labeltext_3.text.SetHint("TRCK ...")
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(labeltext_1, 0, wx.ALL, 10)
        sizer.Add(labeltext_2, 0, wx.ALL, 10)
        sizer.Add(labeltext_3, 0, wx.ALL, 10)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)


class LabelTextSizer(wx.BoxSizer):
    def __init__(self, parent, label, size=wx.DefaultSize, style=0):
        super().__init__(wx.VERTICAL)

        self.label = wx.StaticText(parent, label=label)
        self.text = wx.TextCtrl(parent, size=size)

        self.Add(self.label)
        self.Add(self.text)

if __name__ == '__main__':
        wx_app = wx.App()
        MainFrame()
        wx_app.MainLoop()
```

[image]

Comment: I hope you don't mind, I adjusted the code a bit. Let me know if it's a problem and I'll revert the code back to your original.